# Bootstrap Image Placement Issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the 3 images under the main logo to be divided equally and centred, but I am having issue making the images go into the middle of the page with the other elements.

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated

1. Code below
2. Website is http://www.horizonarb.co.uk

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   Horizon Arboriculture

   ```
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Google Fonts -->
   <script src="js/googleFonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Lobster+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
   <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

   <!-- Font Awesome -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


   <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
   <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   ```

   ```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 10px;">

       <div class="container">

           <div class="navbar-header">

               <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                   <small>MENU</small>
               </button>

            <a href=""><img src="img/front/HorizonArb_Tree_Transparent.png" class="noResize"></a>

           </div> <!-- class="navbar-header" -->

           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

               <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">

                   <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                   <!--
                   <li class="dropdown">
                       <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                         <li><a href="services.html">Crown Thinning</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Crown Lifting</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Crown Reduction</a></li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>-->
                    <li class=""><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

               </ul>

           </div> <!-- class="collapse navbar-collapse" -->

       </div> <!-- class="container" -->

     </div> <!--  class="navbar navbar-default" -->
   ```

   ```
   <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 center marginTopThirty">

           <img src="img/front/HorizonArb_Transparent.png" width="50%">

       </div>

   </div>

   <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 marginTopThirty">

               <img src="img/front/HorizonArb_Transparent.png" width="50%" class="img-responsive">
               <p>Image 1</p>

           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 marginTopThirty">

               <img src="img/front/HorizonArb_Transparent.png" width="50%" class="img-responsive">
               <p>Image 2</p>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 marginTopThirty">

               <img src="img/front/HorizonArb_Transparent.png" width="50%" class="img-responsive">
               <p>Image 3</p>
           </div>   

       </div>

   </div>




   <div class="row">

           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 center marginTopThirty" id="topContainer">



               <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 center">

                   <p class="">Horizon Arboriculture is a professional Cheshire based tree surgery company with a small, expertly trained and qualified work force dedicated to providing high quality service and customer care. We are a Construction Health and Safety Scheme approved contractor (CHAS) that provide our services to both domestic and commercial clients.
   ```

   NPTC and Lantra qualified staff. £10 million public and employers liability insurance. Free, competitive, no obligation quotes.

   ```
               </div>

           </div>

   </div>     


   <div class="footer">

       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 center marginTopThirty" id="topContainer">

           <small class ="center">Design by </small>

       </div>

   </div>
   ```

   ```
   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: Please create a live example, e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (in your CSS):

Set the images' margins to "auto" (margin: auto)

Or:

Set the images to "display: inline-block" and the container to "text-align:center"

Both will center the images in their containers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put `<div class="container">` inside your `<div class="row">` ?

By the way you don't have to put `<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">`
which `<div class="col-lg-12">` does the same

unless you want something like `<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-6">`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've successfully set up your 3-column row, but you just need to center the images (and the text underneath, I'll assume) in their containers.

The easiest way, probably, is to apply `text-align: center` to your divs. Since the images and text are both inline already, we don't need to apply any extra styles to them directly. Using this property will allow any inline element to be centered.

Tested here, along with some other cleanups to your Bootstrap structure:
https://jsfiddle.net/illogicaljake/m5t9smyt/